# Problemas al traer información de StoreProcedure Oracle a C#

Tags: c#, .net, oracle-sqldeveloper

Estoy trabajando oracle con c#, cuando ejecuto mi SP desde C# no me trae ningun resultado, no se si sea mi SP que lo estoy realizando mal o mi codigo pero no me devuelve resultados y si deberia traer ya que hago directa la consulta y hay informacion, tambien verifique que estuviera pasando valor al metodo y si lleva valor

```html
public DataTable ObtenerInformacion(string SECUENCIA)
        {
            using (OracleConnection cn = new OracleConnection("CONNECTION LIFETIME=10;DATA SOURCE=AAA;MAX POOL SIZE=10;PASSWORD=AAA;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=AAA"))
            {
                OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter();
                OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
                cmd.Connection = cn;
                cmd.InitialLONGFetchSize = 1000;
                cmd.CommandText = "sp_datos_estudiante";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("SEQ", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = SECUENCIA;

                da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                return dt;
            }
        }
```

Y mi SP es

```html
CREATE OR REPLACE Procedure sp_datos_estudiante(SEQ IN VARCHAR2)
as
SEQUENCIA transaction.SEQ%Type;
IMPORTE100 transaction.AMOUNT_BEFORE_DISCOUNT%Type;
IMPORTEDESC transaction.AMOUNT_REAL%Type;
Begin
SELECT SEQ,AMOUNT_BEFORE_DISCOUNT, AMOUNT_REAL INTO SEQUENCIA,IMPORTE100,IMPORTEDESC FROM transaction WHERE SEQ=SEQ;
dbms_output.put_line('Codigo :'||SEQUENCIA); dbms_output.put_line('Nombres :'||IMPORTE100); dbms_output.put_line('Especialidad :'||IMPORTEDESC);
end;
```

Comment: Hola yo uso esto con SqlServer supongo que se puede hacer con Oracle var dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
var dataTable = new DataTable();
dataTable.Load(dataReader);

Comment: Te falta abrir la conexión, sino me equivoco

Answer (score 0):

Sino me equivoco, tu problema es que no estas abriendo la conexión para Oracle, sería algo así:

```
public DataTable ObtenerInformacion(string SECUENCIA)
        {
            using (OracleConnection cn = new OracleConnection("CONNECTION LIFETIME=10;DATA SOURCE=AAA;MAX POOL SIZE=10;PASSWORD=AAA;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=AAA"))
            {
                cn.Open(); //Aquí estas abriendo la conexión
                
                OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter();
                OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
                //cmd.Connection = cn; aquí lo único que haces asignarle la variable pero en ningún lado la abres
                cmd.InitialLONGFetchSize = 1000;
                cmd.CommandText = "sp_datos_estudiante";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("SEQ", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = SECUENCIA;

                da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                return dt;
            }
        }
```